# State is different that props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a class like this:

[image]

And I render this class from another class.
But I have some problem. When I try to call component Screen with changed props - state doesnt change.

It is screen from react-tool:

[image]

I call **Screen** directly from Dashboard:

[image]

Props is different than state. I do not know why.

Comment: your state only gets set once in constructor, props can update over the lifecycle of the component which is why you see different props than initially set in state

Comment: can you share how do you change the `page` props too?

Comment: Please paste your code in here instead of taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a best practice to set state with props values. you should use props directly.

constructor lifecycle runs only once when the component loads

if you have changes in data while component is loaded you should use the proper lifecycle to change

componentDidUpdate() that runs after every change. here you can run a setState function and it will updated your component with fresh data.

for more reading about update life cycles : 
[ReactJs componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can solve that situation of 2 ways.
1- you can define goToPage in your state and use props like you do.

```
this.state = {
  gotoPage: props.gotoPage,
  page: props.page,
  data: props.data
}
```

to access that state, use this.state.

2 - How your component just have props, use component stateless and  inside of your component use only props.blabla.

https://itnext.io/react-component-class-vs-stateless-component-e3797c7d23ab

:D